# Product Development using ARM mBED OS

Tags: arm, mbed, os

I have been working on 32-bit ARM cortex controllers writing the code from the grounds up. Now I am looking at ARM mBED OS, but few questions are bothering me. Sorry if it feels too trivial. 
I have a small form factor for my product, using ARM mBED HDK will I be able to achieve it. Ex: say I have a MCU, a display and 2 sensors. To use ARM mBED there are some Hardware requirements, after making room for it will I still be able to meet the small form factor requirement.

Or can we declare mBED based products are only used for prototyping ?

I am in a phase of making a decision as to if I need to continue thinking of ARM mBED as an option or rather better pick an MCU and start configuring it. I just need some clarity on this platform wrt final product development.

Comment: The biggest risk I see with using any off-the-shelf board like that in a 'final product' is what happens if you pick one which isn't popular with others, and it then gets discontinued by the manufacturer due to poor sales .... ? You'll need a backup plan or 2.

Comment: Hi brhans, I don't like to use a 3rd party board in my product. My worries are about making my custom application specific PCB .

Comment: Ah yes - that makes a lot more sense now. Its not at all unusual to use something like that in a commercial product.

Answer (score 2):

ARM mBED is just a software library with a easy to use abstraction layer of typical micro-controller peripherals (SPI, GPIO etc.). It is not even a very complicated one.

Being a software library is has no impact on the form-factor of your final product.

There aren't really any hardware requirements except picking an ARM chip that is supported by mBED. In the end, if your software is working all what's really required to run the mBED code is the micro-controller, a voltage regulator, a hand full of bypass capacitors (and maybe a crystal oscillator if you need precise timing) plus whatever peripheral chips you interface with.

So there is not a big difference to a bare metal system.

Comment: Thanks nils, I see that they have mentioned we need to use their HDK to make use of their mBED OS on their website. Considering that we don't need much of external hardware and I use SDK functions for my project, I am scared thinking about my program size and how to go about optimizing the code.

Comment: @SandeepRavi - Unless you're making tens or hundreds of thousands of devices, the cost of your time to optimize probably far exceeds the cost of using a MCU with more flash memory.